# Python - sending urgent data (tcp)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a problem with sending urgent data in python via TCP.

I have studied the structure of TCP header and the out-of-band data transfer mechanism, but I still can't understand how to implement this..

simple server:

```
#default steps
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn,addr = s.accept()
...
#oob
conn.send('!',MSG_OOB)
...
```

simple client:

```
...
data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE,MSG_OOB)
```

OK, data received.

But how can I indicate that OOB information has come to client when i send data in cycle?

For example:

```
serverFile = open(serverPath, 'rb')
    while True:
        fileBytes = serverFile.read(1000)
        if not fileBytes: break;
        try:
            i += 1
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                print 'sending urgent..'
                conn.send('!',MSG_OOB)
            conn.send(fileBytes)
        except socket.error, (value, message):
            if conn:
                conn.close()
            serverFile.close()
            print 'Error while sending data : error code - ' + str(value) + '; message: ' + message
            exit(1)
    serverFile.close()
```

If client tries to receive all data with 'data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE,MSG_OOB)' - nothing works.
I have not found any way to use SELECT or smth like SIGURG to solve problem.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, TCP OOB data is known to be unreliable, broken and implemented incompatibly in different operating systems. That's why nobody uses it, and in turn that's why nobody cared to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it will help someone (obvious but not particularly efficient solution):
client:

```
#catching urgent data
    s.settimeout(2)
    try:
        data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE,MSG_OOB)
    except socket.error, value: #(value,message):
        #s.settimeout(5)
        data = None
    if data:
        print 'urgent ' + str(data)
    else:
        #recv usual data
        data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def handler(sig_num, frame):
    ....
signal.signal(signal.SIGURG, handler)
fcntl.fcntl(client.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETOWN, os.getpid())
```

This will help to get noticed by OOB data.